# Get the article to extract title, alias, content, etc. Joomla 3.X [PHP]

Tags: php, joomla, get, extract, article

I'm new on this community, and I'll be very grateful if someone can help me with this.

Well, I'm trying to get the information from any article, by ID or by [object].
The idea is, "do some actions" for all of these data, extracting the "title", "content", etc. then manipulate this information.

Some code that I think it could be usefull:

```
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel');
$articles = $model->getItems();
```

"$articles" saves an array, right? which contains all my articles indexed from 0->N.

Now when I use it in a foreach for example, like:

```
foreach($articles as $newArt){
echo $newArt->get("alias");
}
```

"echo" returns nothing.
Actually I tested [echo $articles[0 or 1 ...]; ] same ... nothing.

Any ideas for what is the problem?

Comment: Generally, try debugging output like `var_dump($articles)` or `var_dump($newArt)` to see what it contains.

Comment: Best advice ever ;) Thanks. It was just an array access problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I was wrong calling attributes using `get("alias")`.

```
$newArt->alias;
```

Simple :').

Comment: I'll, but i can't till tomorrow ;)